# Can't start nginx on clean raspi install

Tags: nginx, raspberry-pi

I created a clean Raspi Install and just started with installing nginx, but I can't start it due to errors, what's not quite logical for me with a new install without any changes....

Here's the error:

```
● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2023-09-09 21:00:45 BST; 7min ago
       Docs: man:nginx(8)
    Process: 2660 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 39ms

Sep 09 21:00:45 nodered systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
Sep 09 21:00:45 nodered nginx[2660]: nginx: [emerg] dlopen() "/usr/share/nginx/modules/ngx_http_image_filter_module.so" failed (gets: cannot open shared obje>
Sep 09 21:00:45 nodered nginx[2660]: nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
Sep 09 21:00:45 nodered systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Sep 09 21:00:45 nodered systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 09 21:00:45 nodered systemd[1]: Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
```

Maybe somebody can help me about, sadly I'm not very experienced in Linux/shell Topics...

Clean Installation,

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install nginx
sudo systemctl start nginx
```